# How to implement DNS IP based on full url path

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, domain-name

I know that DNS resolves only domains, but let me explain my problem, I want to know how can I come around this particular requirement.

I have a request from Marketing to make world sites converge into a single domain.

Example, when you had:

```
www.somedomain.com.mx
www.somedomain.co.uk
www.somedomain.co.jp
```

Now they want this:

```
www.somedomain.com/mx
www.somedomain.com/uk
www.somedomain.com/jp
www.somedomain.com
```

But since we have servers in different locations due to latency requirements, they want that:

```
www.somedomain.com goes to the US Server
www.somedomain.com/mx goes to the US Server
www.somedomain.com/uk goes to the UK Server
www.somedomain.com/jp goes to the Japan Server
```

I could set up nginx as reverse proxy, for example in the US:

1. User from Japan visits www.somedomain.com/jp.
2. Nginx answers in www.somedomain.com server (US) and then requests the content from the Japan server, then it relays the response to Japan user.

So: `Japan user -> US nginx -> Japan server -> US nginx -> Japan user`

This would lead to more latency.

Is it possible to have a request for www.somedomain.com/jp answer the IP of a sever that is a mirror of the US server but located in Japan and www.somedomain.com/uk answer  the IP of a mirror server in UK?

So the final infrastructure would be like this:

- `www.somedomain.com mirrored in Japan / US / UK`
- When an user requests `www.somedomain.com/uk`, the requests goes to the IP serving `www.somedomain.com` located in `UK`, which in turn does an internal    request to another IP hosting the UK site, but also located in UK.
- When an user requests `www.somedomain.com/jp`, the requests goes to the IP serving `www.somedomain.com` located in `Japan`, which in turn does an internal request to another IP hosting the Japan site, but also located in Japan.

Comment: Their set of requirements is kind of contradictory as the first scheme by using separate TLDs immediately gives you the feature of websites separated in different countries as needed. Instead, `/mx` query should be rewritten to the `.mx` domain name, etc...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek they want to be in the same domain because of SEO ranking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this can not be accomplished with just DNS.

A few things you should be considering instead:

- A CDN
- Geographic routing of DNS queries (for example, AWS Route 53 [supports this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html))

Comment: Thanks, since DNS is only for domains name (not taking care of the rest of the URL path), Route 53 could not evaluate that, right?

Comment: Right - geo-DNS is a common approach to sending users to the closest server, but it doesn't work exactly as you specify. A CDN gets you closer - AWS CloudFront has dozens of CDN endpoints on six continents, and allows you to send paths like `/mx/*` to specific backends.